# How to use env variable on kubernetes script?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

I have this kubernetes script on [argo workflows](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/) template

```
- name: rendition-composer
  inputs:
    parameters:
      - name: original_resolution
  script:
    image: node:9.1-alpine
    command: [node]
    source: |
      // some node.js script
      ...
      console.log($(SD_RENDITION));
    volumeMounts: 
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: /mnt/vol
    - name: config
      mountPath: /config
      readOnly: true
    env:
      - name: SD_RENDITION
        valueFrom: 
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: rendition-specification           
            key: res480p
```

In here `console.log($(SD_RENDITION));` I can't get the env value. it returns error

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I already did all the setup for the ConfigMap on [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) kubernetes official documentation

Is there anything I miss?

Comment: Why don't you use template argument instead?

Comment: I really new to kubernetes. If I use template argument, how do I put my nodejs file into the pod? A link about that might help

Comment: I thought your question was solving the error. but are you trying to find a way to put a file into a pod? If so, what is the problem using ConfigMap to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
process.env.SD_RENDITION
```

The above syntax solved my problem. It seems I miss some essential concepts about js' `process` object